# How do I know if this function works in time O(N) and memory O(N)?

Tags: c++, arrays, big-o

The task is:

> Given is an array containing `N` numbers, `A[0],A[1],...A[N-1]`. Compute the array `B` of length `N`, such that `B[i]=A[0]*A[1]*...A[i-1]*A[i+1]...*A[N-1]`. You shouldn't use division and both time and memory complexity should be `O(N)`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>

long int find_solution(int result, int multiplier, int increment)
{
    int safety=1;
    long int solution=0;
    while(safety==1)
    {
        if (solution*multiplier==result)
        {
            safety=0;
            return solution;    
        }
        else if((solution+increment)*multiplier>result)
        {
            safety=0;
            return find_solution(result,multiplier, increment*0.1);
        }
        solution=solution+increment;
    }
}

int main()
{
    double time_spent=0.0;
    int A[20] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6,1,2,3,4,5,1,1,1,2,3,1,1,1,1,1};
    clock_t begin=clock();
    int i;
    long int main_result=1;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        main_result=main_result*A[i];
    }
    printf("\n%d\n",main_result);
    long int B[20];
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        B[i]=find_solution(main_result, A[i],100000000);
    }
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",B[i]);
    }
    clock_t end=clock();
    time_spent=(double)(end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time elapsed: %.20f\n",time_spent);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I analyzed this function myself and it seems OK. When I calculate the time on the computer, it's fine if the input is `5,10,15` (I made 21 measures for each amount of input). When it's `20`, the time starts growing more than it probably should.

```
5-0.01333333
10-0.02276
15-0.03757
20-0.07066
```

What might be the reason? I didn't use any nested loops. Is my function OK?

Comment: what is the unit of the time you measured? You shuold increase the workload more, because the constant and linear part of complexity might dominate for small input size while higher orders might only be significant with larger input sizes

Comment: FYI, `find_solution` has code paths that do *not* provide a proper return value (i.e. any at all). Fix that, fix the improper printf format specifiers (`long int` should be printed with `%ld` , not `%d`), test your code as optimized build, and including your build command as part of your question.

Comment: *" I didn't use any nested loops.."* But recursive function might act as loop

Comment: Same comment that for your previous question, `while(safety==1)` -> `while (true)` and get rid of `safety` (which doesn't provide any safety at all BTW).

Comment: With `for(i=0;i<20;i++)`, `while(safety==1)`, `return find_solution(..);` you have 2 nested loops.

Comment: Your `find_solution` purpose is to do a division (without the division), expected solution is not to reimplement division, but avoid it.

Comment: `int left[20]; int right[20]; std::partial_sum(std::begin(A), std::end(A), std::begin(left), std::multiplies<int>()); std::partial_sum(std::rbegin(A), std::rend(A), std::rbegin(right), std::multiplies<int>());` might help.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks! But can you explain it a little bit? I thought that if the function is recursive it will return a value anyway (at least in this case). What did you mean with "a proper return value"?

Comment: Also I saw these nested loops before, but just thought that their runtime doesn't depend on the amount of input. It seems completely random (seems that it depends on the numbers which are given to the find_solution function and not on the amount of input in the array). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest generating much larger inputs to test time complexity, for example N1=100000, N2=200000 ... . For small inputs and small timeframes compilers, caches and other processes may impact the time you measure, and shouldnt be part of your analysis.

Your algorithm looks to be O(N) to me, as find_solution() is constant time and is not called more than some constant times. A very cool and creative solution to the problem, however, you might just be reinventing division as you are answering the question "what multiplied by the denominator equals the numerator".

My solution after thinking a little is to for each index calculate the product of all elements to the right, this can be done in O(N) time. Do the same for the other side and multiply the sides together and you have B, right?

EDIT: Also, when discussing time complexity, measurements are fine but they do not "prove" the time complexity, that has to be done manually by understanding the time complexity of different parts of the algorithm and analysing how many times something is ran.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's absolutely true. Bigger input makes the measurements a lot more sensible. Yeah, I see my mistakes and anyway my solution takes a looot of time for big input. I tried the method you described too and it works a lot better and it's O(N) for sure. Great idea!

Comment: Note that an incorrect implementation of my algorithm will give you O(N^2) time as for each element you need to read and multiply all other elements. To get O(N) you need to make an additional optimization, I think you can figure it out ;)

Answer (score -1):

O(N) means that the algorithm should take N operations, which is limited to the input array size of A in your case.

At main function the loop iterates 20 times but within "find_solution" method loop the complexity duplicates.

I think you are a bit confused, your task requires just the multiplication of each item of A for all B's whatever the i of B is:

```
B[i]=A[0]A[1]...A[i-1]*A[i+1]...*A[N-1].
```

So multiply each item of A once, and put it into all B's within a for loop of N is O(N).

Comment: not quite correct. `O(N)` means that it takes `N + c` operations where `c` can be arbitrarily large but constant

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number - That's not correct either.  `O(N)` formally means that, in the limit as `N` approaches infinity, that the number of operations converges on being linear with `N`.   Or, less formally,  as `N` gets large, a plot of number of operations versus `N` gets closer to being proportional to `N`.

Comment: @Peter isnt that the same ? `N^2` (or any higher order constribution) can only appraoch `N` when `N` goes to infinity when it comes with a `/N` factor, ie it is actually `N`. Anyhow, if your point was that my comment wasnt accurate I completely agree, it should have been `c1 * N + c2`

Comment: @Peter oh well, I now see the fault in my reasoning. I was only considering polynomials, but it could be `O(N^2)` for lets say `N <100` and `O(N)` for `N >= 100`

Comment: @Peter oh well, I now see the fault in my reasoning. I was only considering polynomials, but it could be `O(N^2)` for lets say `N <100` and `O(N)` for `N >= 100`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: `N + log(N)` is still `O(N)` even if it is not `a * N + b`. Issue when we want to simplify, is that it is easy to no longer 100% correct (especially true in C++ with so many corner cases :-/ ).

Comment: @Jarod42 right, I was more wrong than I thaught. My point was just that "O(N) means that the algorithm should take N operations" is not correct, and I should have refrained from trying to correct it in the comment

Comment: @cagilozturk: Not sure what you propose as O(N) solution. `B[i]` is (ignoring `0`) `ProductOfAs / A[i]`. The Bruteforce method to recompute `ProductofAs without A[i]` is `O(N)` by `i` so `O(N²)` for whole `B`.